Conexion a Puerto Serial(Bascula) con C#
Buen dia a todos solicitando de su ayuda, estoy desarrollando una aplicacion Windows Form con C# el problema es que ya configure todo para que mi puerto COM4 en el que esta conectada la bascula me devuelva los datos pero cuando ejecuto el programa y me muestra el form el label en el que deberia verse la informacion del peso de la bascula no se esta mostrando se queda vacia.
Podrian ayudar y saber que estoy haciendo mal
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading;

namespace BasculaApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private delegate void DelegadoAcceso(string accion);
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                serialPort1 = new SerialPort("COM4", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
                serialPort1.Handshake = Handshake.None;
                serialPort1.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(sp_DataReceived);
                serialPort1.ReadTimeout = 500;
                serialPort1.WriteTimeout = 500;
                serialPort1.Open();
                serialPort1.Write("0P");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        void sp_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.Enabled == true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                string data = serialPort1.ReadLine();
                this.BeginInvoke(new DelegadoAcceso(si_DataReceived), new object[] { data });
            }
        }

        private void si_DataReceived(string accion)
        {
            label2.Text = accion;

        }
    }
}



Por ejemplo mi form al ejecutarlo se ve asi yo por defaul le agregue se vea el 0 pero de igual manera no me muestra valor alguno de la bascula
Ya realice pruebas con hyperterminal y al presionar la tecla print de mi bascula me muestra la informacion en hyperterminal, la configuracion es la misma que la de mi codigo entonces sigo sin saber cual es el problema real
Agrego imagenes como evidencia

Y esta otra de la bascula


Por lo general le tienes que mandar un comando al puerto y regresa el peso.
por lo general es una "P", pero, dependiendo de la bascula puede cambiar, revisa ese punto

@MrDonPh0x Tendria que revisarlo directamente en la pagina del fabricante de la bascula?

@Yussef ya lo hice, pero continua igual sin devolverme algun valor al label de echo ya agregue una imagen de mi form

No tengo certeza realmente, Ya que ni en el error list de visual studio me muestra algun error no se si el problema realmente este en el codigo o la bascula

Muchas gracias por el comentario, de echo ya probe con solo "P" y no me devolvio nada lo intentare con el brinco de linea y con el de tipo terminal serial

@Yussef ya actualice mi pregunta utilice hyperterminal

¿Por qué tienes el if (this.Enabled?. ¿Por qué llamas a Sleep()? ¿No sería más sencillo poner la cadena en un miembro de la clase y sincronizar un método sin parámetros?

Pregunto porque no tengo una báscula u otro dispositivo serial a mano para hacer una prueba rápida con tu código, pero sospecho que entre la combinación de esas 3 cosas está tu problema.  Si me confirmas, con gusto escribo una respuesta.

¿En qué parte de su código establece que "this.Enabled" sea "true"?  No puedo verlo.
